# Generalizing AES s-box circular shifts in bigger GF

Tags: aes, s-boxes

According to wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box

AES is doing interesting thing (where $<<<$ is circular shift):

$s = b \oplus (b \lll 1) \oplus (b \lll 2) \oplus (b \lll 3) \oplus (b \lll 4)$

and this is equal to ($\times$ is multiplication in $GF(2^8)$):

$s = b \times 31 \mod 257$

This provides a great bit of mixing to my eye. Let's say I have 128 bit $x$ and $y$ and I want to compute something similar:

$x = y \oplus (y \lll 1) \oplus (y \lll 2) \oplus (y \lll 3) \oplus ... \oplus (y \lll 64)$

Can I do it faster using multiplication in $GF(2^{128}) \mod 2^{128}+1$? I don't know the theory behind this, so I have two types of multipliers for this:

$2^{125}-1$

and

$2^{65}-1$

I think this second one may work in the same way in $GF(2^{128})$, this is the rule. So is there a similar number that I can use? What is that number?

EDIT: It looks like there is mistake in article and circular shift could be in other direction:

$s = b \oplus (b \ggg 1) \oplus (b \ggg 2) \oplus (b \ggg 3) \oplus (b \ggg 4)$

Anyway, can we generalize it? In this document there is nothing about equality to GF multiplication of that step:

https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/197/final/documents/fips-197.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the left vs right shift issue has to do with if the variable is represented by "big-endian" or "little-endian" convention, i.e., if the Least Significant Bit is on the left or on the right.

The operation:

$$s = b \oplus (b \lll 1) \oplus (b \lll 2) \oplus (b \lll 3) \oplus (b \lll 4)$$

is equivalent to the multiplication (where the shift is $\times x$ below)

$$
s(x)=b(x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)=b(x)\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}
$$
but since left shift is also doubling, let $x=2,$ to get $s(x)=(2^5-1)b(x).$ In any case cyclic shift is equivalent to operating $\pmod x^n-1$ where $n$ is the wordlength in bits.

Your second operation is indeed equivalent to multiplication by $2^{65}-1.$

Since you seem mathematically capable enough, I'd suggest:

Read the document "AES Proposal" by Daemen and Rijmen in full to get familiar with these types of operations and representations. There is also the book *The Design of Rijndael* by the same authors. You are learning about the interplay between Galois Fields of characteristic 2, $GF(2^n)$ and integer rings $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n-1}$ which can also be "decomposed" into $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n/2}-1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n/2}+1},$ when $n$ is even. Another place to look is documentation regarding the design of SAFER-64 by Jim Massey. More generally Number Theoretic Transforms (NTTs) which generalize the Fast Fourier Transform.

If you have recursive decompositions of the type I mentioned above, you have fast implementations. The simplest such transform is the Sylvester Hadamard matrix used in Fast Walsh-Hadamard transforms where $n$ Kronecker products of the same matrix $H_2$ is used:
$$
H_n =H_2 \otimes H_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes H_2
$$
with
$$
H_2=\left[\begin{array}{cc} +1 & +1 \\ +1 & -1 \end{array} \right].
$$
Since this is *the* Fourier transform for the binary vector space $GF(2)^n=\{0,1\}^n$ equivalently the rows of the Hadamard matrix above are the group characters of the additive group of $(\mathbb{GF(2)^n},\oplus)$ it all makes sense.

Anyway, happy reading.

Comment: I have second question about number 99. I suspect this is about some sort of balancing the most significant bit problem (if I'm right, this even could be a problem), which are always equal to 1 in every number. But I can't make an equivalent of that number for my example. Do you know where the number 99 came from? What there could be in GF(2^128)?

Comment: I'm trying to check it by hand and this doesn't work for me. Is there reduction by some polynomial or is x 31 just carry-less multiplication? In both cases it seem doesn't work. Let's take b = 10000001. b <<< 1 = 000000011. b <<< 2 = 00000110. b <<< 3 = 00001100. b <<< 4 = 00011000. So xor = 10000001 ^ 00000011 ^ 00000110 ^ 00001100 ^ 00011000 = 10010000. This is not equal to 129 x 31 in GF(2^8), which is 111110011111. I didn't try to reduce it by some polynomial, but I don't believe it would give right result. Is there really circular shift or normal bitwise shift???

Comment: I reduced it by polynomial x^9+1. And finally it works.

Answer (score 2):

I calculated the matrix from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) and independently calculated the xor-rotation sequence from the matrix.

The matrix I calculated matches the Wikipedia article

```
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}
  {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
  {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}
  {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
  {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

The matrix was calculated using the formula

$$s=\left(b\times 31_{10}\mod {257_{10}}\right)$$

I automatically calculated the following xor-rotation sequence from the matrix

```
(b <<< 0) xor (b <<< 1) xor (b <<< 2) xor (b <<< 3) xor (b <<< 4)
```

which matches the sequence of operations on the Wikipedia page.

I made a 128x128 matrix from the formula

$$s=\left(b\times 31_{10}\mod c\right)$$

where I chose the constant $c$ to be the bit array represented by the polynomial, $c = x^{128} - 1$. I did not change the constant $31_{10}$ from the original formula.

I cannot paste the matrix here as it is very large. It is full of zeros and is just a cyclic shift of the $31_{10}$ constant.

The xor-rotation sequence that I computed for the matrix is

```
(b <<< 0) xor (b <<< 1) xor (b <<< 2) xor (b <<< 3) xor (b <<< 4)
```

This might be slightly surprising as it is identical to the GF(2^8) case however it is just one rotation term for each nonzero component of the $31_{10}$ constant. The rotations are for a 128-bit vector, of course.

I tested 1,000,000 random inputs using both the matrix and xor-rotation versions of this GF(2^128) generalization and found that the outputs were identical.

Comment: How did you define b <<< 1. Let's take 8-bit number b=10000001. What is b <<< 1?

Comment: And is mod 257 is mod polynomial x^8+1 in GF(s^8) or is this just normal modulo operation?

Answer (score 1):

There is something misleading in Wikipedia article. They wrote:

$s = b \oplus (b \lll 1) \oplus (b \lll 2) \oplus (b \lll 3) \oplus (b \lll 4)$

Is equal to:

$s = b \times 31 \mod 257$

where $\times$  is polynomial multiplication of $b$ and $31$ taken as bit arrays. But $\mod 257$ is not standard modulo operation, it is mod in $GF(2^8)$ and $257$ is in fact polynomial of the form $x^{9}+1$.

We can easily see that carry-less multiplication of $b \times 31$ is equal to:

$s = b \oplus (b \ll 1) \oplus (b \ll 2) \oplus (b \ll 3) \oplus (b \ll 4)$

in bits $7,6,5,4$, where $\ll$ is bitwise shift, not circualr sfift. But in Wikipedia example and in AES there is circular shift. So where does circular come from? It comes from reduction by the polynomial $x^9+1$. This is how multiplication with polynomial reduction works in $GF(2^8)$:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <bitset>
#include<iostream>


uint8_t multiply(uint a, uint b)
    {
        uint8_t p = 1;
        uint16_t L = 1;
        uint16_t c = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            c ^= a & (L << i) ? (uint16_t)b << i : 0;
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 8; i-- > 0; )
        {
            if (c & (L << (i + 8)))
            {
                c ^= L << (i + 8);
                c ^= (uint16_t)p << i;
            }
        }

        return (uint8_t)c;
    }

int main()
{
    uint result = 0;
    
    result = multiply(131,31);
    std::cout << result;
    
    return 0;
}
```

We need polynomial of degree $9$, but we can define reducing polynomial in practical implementation by taking only its first $8$ least significant bits, so in our case $p=1$. Now if we look how carry-less multiplication works (first loop), we can see that in $7,6,5,4$ bits we would get the same result, as with shifts:

$s = b \oplus (b \ll 1) \oplus (b \ll 2) \oplus (b \ll 3) \oplus (b \ll 4)$

But in place of bits $11,10,9,8$ will be exactly bits shifted (canceled) out in process of bitwise shift. This is because carry-less multiplication move them to the left by $1,2,3...$ positions and then all is xored. Like here:

[image]

Since we are multiplicating by $31$ we would get always $4$ extra bits in higher significant half of our 16-bit result. And they would be xored, because this is how carry-less multiplication works. So now we got bits $7,6,5,4$ equal to the result of:

$s = b \oplus (b \ll 1) \oplus (b \ll 2) \oplus (b \ll 3) \oplus (b \ll 4)$

And bits $11,10,9,8$, which could be in place of bits $3,2,1,0$. To make circular shift we need to only xor back this bits. This is done by:

```
for (unsigned int i = 8; i-- > 0; )
        {
            if (c & (L << (i + 8)))
            {
                c ^= L << (i + 8);
                c ^= (uint16_t)p << i;
            }
        }
```

If $p=1$. We can see that this code is really checking is there bit equal to $1$ on the left on position $i$ of our top half, and if it is, then it xor that bit with bit $i$ on our low half. And all that algorithm is equal to xoring with circialr shift $\lll$:

$s = b \oplus (b \lll 1) \oplus (b \lll 2) \oplus (b \lll 3) \oplus (b \lll 4)$

Knowing this it becomes clear that this kind of equivalence holds for any $GF(2^k)$, provided we choose $p=1$ (by the convention of the posted code) as our polynomial and multiplier equal to $2^{\frac {k}{2}+1}-1$.

Comment: In $\LaTeX$ there is `\ll \lll \gg` and `\ggg` to produce $\ll, \quad \lll, \quad \gg \quad \text{ and } \quad \ggg$